# $2:1$ coverings of $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I am trying to determine the number of $2:1$ coverings of of the wedge sum $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$. I know that proposition $1.32$ in Hatchers Algebraic Topology says that if $p:(X,x_0) \to (B,b_0)$ is a covering map, then the number of sheets of a covering is equal to the the index of the of $p_*(\pi_1(X,x_0))$ in $\pi_1(B,b_0)$. Thus, I think that this amounts to finding the number of index 2 subgroups in $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} *\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$. Is this the correct approach or is there something else to consider.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, that's a sound approach.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I know this is a question more of algebra, but how do you find index 2 subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}?$

Comment: To find the index two subgroups of some group $G$, I'd consider homomorphisms $G\to\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Is there 3 such coverings ($2\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z} , \mathbb{Z}*2\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*2\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: Eh, on second thought, it seems like there are 7 surjective homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Yes, any map to $\Bbb Z_2$ would factor through the abelianization, which is $\Bbb Z^3$, and since the three coordinate copies of $2\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb Z^3$ are in the kernel it would factor further through $\Bbb Z_2^3$.